# Regex to extract information from a paragraph

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract a few pieces of information in a given paragraph.

Eg Input:

```
xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx
Status : In Stock        Warranty : One Year       SKU : A12345
xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx
```

Data I wanna extract are:

1. Status
2. Warranty
3. SKU

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any particular language you are using? If we know this it will be easier for us and for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines?

```
/Status\s?:\s?(.+)\s?Warranty\s?:\s?(.+)\s?SKU\s?:\s?(.+)\s?/
```

Try it: http://rubular.com/r/p5JcJxRO6U

Comment: @Homer Well, the example *does* work (see link), so you'll need to give us some more information on *what* doesn't work and what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry deceze, for some reason it works now, I think i might have copied the "/" at the beginning and the end. Also how can I remove the empty spaces after the 3 values? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Actually I also noticed the SKU value also included the xxxxxx on the next line. How do u remove the trailing line break after the SKU value?

Comment: @Homer The RegEx *should* ignore the surrounding whitespace, but again, *that may depend on your RegEx engine*. You can just use the `trim` function or its equivalent of whatever language you're using, which, again, I don't know since you're not giving us any information.

Comment: i'm actually using a program (a web scraping tool)
that allow me to put in regex expresssions to transform bits of content. So I assume it's just the "standard" regex, not Perl or something...do the "standard" regex have trim functions?

Answer (score 0):

If using PCRE or the like:

```
/\bStatus\s*:\s*((?:(?!Warranty).)*)\b\s+Warranty\s*:\s*((?:(?!SKU).)*)\b\s+SKU\s*:\s*(\S+)/i;
```

Comment: Qtax, dunno what PCRE is...but what deceze gave me actually worked. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: PCRE is a regex library used in many tools and languages. The above is tested to work in Perl, PHP, etc.